# javax.naming.NamingException, Tomcat7 and Struts2 can't access to DB resource via JNDI

Tags: java, database, hibernate, tomcat, struts2

I'm developing new web app with Struts2 framework, eclipse, and I've mapped the db structure with Hibernate. The problem is that when I execute my "list" action the framework returns me this error:

```
    Struts Problem Report

    Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

    Messages:   
    This context must be accessed through a java: URL
    Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/main]
    File:   org/apache/naming/SelectorContext.java
    Line number:    776
```

The server.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource auth="Container" defaultAutoCommit="false" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="200" maxIdle="100" maxWait="20000" name="jdbc/main" password="########" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.4.1.85/SBAGRU_DEV" username="****"/>

    </GlobalNamingResources>
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector connectionTimeout="2000" executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

        <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="C:\jpeople.bin" keystorePass="gesbanke" keystoreType="PKCS12" maxThreads="200" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="SSL"/>

        <!--<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/> -->
        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false"> 
                <Context docBase="mag0" path="/mag0" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mag0">
                    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/main" name="jdbc/main" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
                </Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

I've also hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource auth="Container" defaultAutoCommit="false" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="200" maxIdle="100" maxWait="20000" name="jdbc/main" password="########" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.4.1.85/SBAGRU_DEV" username="****"/>

    </GlobalNamingResources>
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector connectionTimeout="2000" executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

        <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="C:\jpeople.bin" keystorePass="******" keystoreType="PKCS12" maxThreads="200" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="SSL"/>

        <!--<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/> -->
        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false"> 
                <Context docBase="mag0" path="/mag0" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mag0">
                    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/main" name="jdbc/main" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
                </Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Any suggestion where I can look? I'm really going crazy!

Comment: You have not posted the hibernate config. Its same config as server.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the **solution**, and the **real problem**. I edit the *server.xml* in *Eclipse*, and I didn't watch the real publish result. For strange reason *eclipse* remove the resource link in the real *server.xml*, but show me the link in *eclipse* view. So i gooogled all day long and I find that I must add in the *context.xml* file under *WEB-INF* directory this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="">
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/main" name="jdbc/main" type="javax.sql.DataSource" /> 
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a link to the resource in your web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>JTDS Datasource</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/main</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

for more info, check the Tomcat Docs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: I found the solution...and the  real problem:

Answer (score 0):

Generally a JDBC datasource is also configured as `<Resource>` as follows

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/main" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="******" password="######" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.4.1.85/SBAGRU_DEV"/>
```

You can try this inside  tag. Just replace `<ResourceLink>` by above `<Resource>` element.

What you have done appears correct as  `<ResourceLink>`  is used to link the resources defined in `<GlobalNamingResources>` not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!I found the **solution**, and the **real problem**. I edit the server.xml in Eclipse, and I didn't watch the real publish result. For strange reason eclipse remove the resource link in the real server.xml put show me it on eclipse. So i gooogled all day long and I find that I must add in the context.xml file under WEB-INF directory this:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="">
   <ResourceLink global="jdbc/main" name="jdbc/main"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</Context>`

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at this link
[Hibernate + Tomcat 7](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7099)

I have faced on the same problem: after the Tomcat update, this bug has disappeared.