# Configure hibernate 4 to connect to database via JNDI Datasource in tomcat 7

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, tomcat7, jndi

I am using Tomcat7,Struts-2.3.5,hibernate-4.1.7 and jotm-2.1.9 width microsoft sqlserver 2005 as my java web application framework. when I use jndi datasource in hibernate configurarion, it refuse to work. I have read a seemingly post in this site,[Configure hibernate to connect to database via JNDI Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303671/configure-hibernate-to-connect-to-database-via-jndi-datasource/13107547#comment17817603_13107547),did not solve the problem.
1, I put the resource definition in tomcat server.xml,not context.xml under META-INF ;

```
<Context docBase="C:\workspace\javaspaces\sitexa\web"
privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" antiJARLocking="false">
<Resource name="jdbc/sitexaDB"
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
factory="org.objectweb.jotm.datasource.DataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=sitexa"
username="sa" password=""/>
<Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container"         type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction" />
 </Context>
```

2, I put all libs need for database connection and jta under the tomcat folder /lib;

3, in web.xml:

```
<resource-env-ref>
<description>DB Connection</description>
<resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/sitexaDB</resource-env-ref-name>
<resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

4, in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<session-factory>

<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/sitexaDB</property>

<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>


<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JOTMJtaPlatform</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
...
</session-factory>
```

5, exception:

```
%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%
org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/sitexaDB]
at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed through a java: URL
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.parseName(SelectorContext.java:776)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:135)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905364/javax-naming-namingexception-tomcat7-and-struts2-cant-access-to-db-resource-vi

Comment: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7099

Comment: solved the jndi problem by upgrade tomcat 7.0.25 to 7.0.32,----it is a tomcat bug.

Comment: Cool the second link was correct then. Glad you got it working.

Comment: You have naming exception, che your Jnds published properly.

Comment: Hibernate won't connect you to jndi it should lookup through the API.

Answer (score -1):

Add the data in context.xml in server.

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/sitexaDB" name="jdbc/sitexaDB" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<Resource name="jdbc/sitexaDB" global="jdbc/sitexaDB" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=sitexa" username="sa" password=""/>
```